# Git apply changes from master to derived branch

Tags: git, github

I know this question get asked a lot around here, but after following all the answers I still can't understand something.

I have a branch called "video-messaging" which is the derived from the "master". After working a bit on "video-messaging" I encountered a bug, realizing I cannot continue to work on this feature without the fix, I asked the programmer who's responsible for that part of code to fix it, he fixed it and uploaded it to the "master". Now, I tried to `git rebase` "video-messaging" with  "master" to get those changes and now I have the fix listed along with the rest of the commits made after the creation of "video-message" both from "master" and from "video-message" when typing `git log video-message`. Great, Right? no... I can't see the fixes when looking at the actual source code! And hence I can't compile the project and continue testing my new feature.

Well I know that it rebased because the commits are all there, but why can't I see it in the actual code?

Comment: `git rebase video-messaging origin/master` is what I think you want.  You seem to want to rebase the remote branch, if it is remote.  Otherwise you are still referring to your local branch.  If you have not fetched the remote branch, it is not surprising you can't see it.

Comment: I've tried to do the same with the origin/* branches, but it resulted in the same problem. Anyway, since this branch ended up with a lot of multiply commits and merging going wrong etc... I ended up deleting this branch and added my changes manually to the master branch. Sometimes git can be confusing but I guess this was just me making a mess.

Comment: It sounds like your rebase was 'backwards'.  This does take some getting used to though.  Sounds like you finally got it straightened out.